# OpenLayers WFS with array of featureType shows just one featureType

Tags: gis, openlayers

I have WFS service with 2 layers and want to display both layers in one Vector layer:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('test', {
    styleMap: style,
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: '1.1.0',
        srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
        url: 'http://XXX/WFSServer?request=GetFeature&typeName=pref:type1,pref:type2',
        featureType: ['type1', 'type2'],
        singleFeatureType: false,
        featurePrefix: 'pref',
        geometryName: 'Shape',
        readFormat: new OpenLayers.Format.GML.v3({ xy: false })
    })
});
```

And OpenLayers show just pref:type1

What am I missing in configuration?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you overspecified the url. I would set it to

`http://XXX/WFSServer`

and let OL create the request based on your parameters.

Compare to [this example](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS-js.html)

Comment: I can verify this is the correct approach. Let OpenLayers build the entire request or you'll get inconsistent behavior.